# Remove specific duplicates from df/list of lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas df (dummy df, original has around 50'000 rows).

```
columns = ['question_id', 'answer', 'is_correct']
data = [['1','hello','1.0'],
       ['1','hello', '1.0'],
       ['1','hello', '1.0'],
        ['2', 'dog', '0.0'],
        ['2', 'cat', '1.0'],
        ['2', 'dog', '0.0'],
        ['2', 'the answer is cat', '1.0'],
        ['3', 'Milan', '1.0'],
        ['3', 'Paris', '0.0'],
        ['3', 'The capital is Paris', '0.0'],
        ['3', 'MILAN', '1.0'],
        ['4', 'The capital is Paris', '1.0'],
        ['4', 'London', '0.0'],
        ['4', 'Paris', '1.0'],
        ['4', 'paris', '1.0'],
        ['5', 'lol', '0.0'],
        ['5', 'rofl', '0.0'],
        ['6', '5.5', '1.0'],
        ['6', '5.2', '0.0']]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, data=data)
```

I want to return a list of lists. An inner list should contain exactly two correct (is_correct = 1.0) answers (a1_correct and a2_correct) and one incorrect (is_correct = 0.0) answer (a_incorrect) from the same question. **Important**: if a1_correct equals a2_correct, then skip that question, I do not want to have duplicates with a1_correct and a2_correct. One inner list per question_id. The other answers within a question_id can simply be ignored.

Edge cases:

- All answers are correct -> Skip this question
- All correct answers are duplicates -> Skip this question
- No answer is correct -> Skip this question. E.g. output None. See question_id = 5
- Only one answer is correct -> Skip this question. E.g. output
  None. See question_id = 5

What I want the output to look like:

```
[['cat', 'the answer is cat', 'dog'], ['Milan', 'MILAN', 'Paris'], ['The capital is Paris', 'paris', 'London']]
```

My current approach includes the duplicates, how can I fix that? Should I first remove the duplicates from the df and then create the list of lists?

```
import builtins

def create_triplet(grp):
    is_correct = grp['is_correct'] == 1.0
    is_wrong = grp['is_correct'] == 0.0
    if (is_correct.value_counts().get(True, 0) >= 2) and is_wrong.any():
      a1_correct = grp['answer'][is_correct].iloc[0]
      a2_correct = grp['answer'][is_correct].iloc[1]
      #here I tried to ignore duplicates but it doesn't work
      if a1_correct == a2_correct:
        return
      else: grp['answer'][is_correct].iloc[1]
      incorrect = grp['answer'][is_wrong].iloc[0]
      return [a1_correct, a2_correct, incorrect]

triplets_raw = df.groupby('question_id').apply(create_triplet)
triplets_list = list(builtins.filter(lambda x: (x is not None), triplets_raw.to_list()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want any duplicates for the correct answers, use drop_duplicates() before selecting the 2 correct answers to remove any duplicates in the correct answers. 2 answers selected from these will be unique. Then somehow select (up to) 2 answers and similarly for the wrong answers.

After selecting correct and wrong answers, if I understood correctly, create_triplets should only return something when there are 2 correct and 1 wrong answers to return.
For example, len() works fine for this.

I modified the code you provided a little bit, which produced the expected output.

There's also some comments in the code and sample outputs after the code for clarifying what the code does.

```
import pandas as pd

def create_triplet(grp):
    # Select unique, correct answers
    correct = grp.loc[grp['is_correct'] == '1.0', 'answer'].drop_duplicates()
    # Select up to 2 correct answers and change to a list
    correct = list(correct.iloc[:2])
    # Repeat similarly to wrong answers expect only take up to 1 correct answer(s)
    # The same thing in one line
    # May or may not be easier to read, use whichever you prefer
    # Note: drop_duplicates is not necessary here
    wrong = list(grp.loc[grp['is_correct'] == '0.0', 'answer'].drop_duplicates().iloc[:1])
    # Question should not be skipped when there are (at least)
    # 2 different but correct answers and 1 wrong answer
    if len(correct) == 2 and len(wrong) == 1:
        return correct + wrong
    # Otherwise signify skipping the question by returning None
    return None


columns = ['question_id', 'answer', 'is_correct']
data = [
    ['1', 'hello', '1.0'],
    ['1', 'hello', '1.0'],
    ['1', 'hello', '1.0'],
    ['2', 'dog', '0.0'],
    ['2', 'cat', '1.0'],
    ['2', 'dog', '0.0'],
    ['2', 'the answer is cat', '1.0'],
    ['3', 'Milan', '1.0'],
    ['3', 'Paris', '0.0'],
    ['3', 'The capital is Paris', '0.0'],
    ['3', 'MILAN', '1.0'],
    ['4', 'The capital is Paris', '1.0'],
    ['4', 'London', '0.0'],
    ['4', 'Paris', '1.0'],
    ['4', 'paris', '1.0'],
    ['5', 'lol', '0.0'],
    ['5', 'rofl', '0.0'],
    ['6', '5.5', '1.0'],
    ['6', '5.2', '0.0']
]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, data=data)
expected = [
    ['cat', 'the answer is cat', 'dog'],
    ['Milan', 'MILAN', 'Paris'],
    ['The capital is Paris', 'paris', 'London']
]

triplets_raw = df.groupby('question_id').apply(create_triplet)
# Triplets_raw is a pandas Series with values being either
# a list of valid responses or None
# dropna() removes rows with None-values, leaving only rows with lists
# The resulting Series is then changed to list as required
triplest_list = list(triplets_raw.dropna())
```

Some outputs:

```
>>> df.groupby('question_id').apply(create_triplet)
question_id
1                                     None
2            [cat, the answer is cat, dog]
3                    [Milan, MILAN, Paris]
4    [The capital is Paris, Paris, London]
5                                     None
6                                     None
>>> triplets_raw = df.groupby('question_id').apply(create_triplet)
>>> list(triplets_raw.dropna())
[['cat', 'the answer is cat', 'dog'], ['Milan', 'MILAN', 'Paris'], ['The capital is Paris', 'Paris', 'London']]
```

Comment: Amazing, especially the comments at each step! 10/10. Works on my dummy df but not on my original df. `triplets_raw` returns an empty list somehow. Not sure yet why.

Comment: Thanks again! I solved my problem. I stored 1.0 and 0.0 as floats and not as strings in my original df.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)